# Storing long hex value

Tags: mysql, mariadb

What is the best way to store long hex string that has more then 1500 chars?

What is the best type?

1. Byte
2. Text
3. LongText
4. VarChar

Comment: Can you guess the max limit?

Comment: Why don't you check MySQL documentation instead of asking a SOF question? Why not using google? Y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `BINARY` have fixed padding and a maximum length of **255 byte**,
  so it's no good for you.
- `VARCHAR` and `TEXT` have both a maximum length of
  **65535 bytes (64kB)** and uses **2 more extra bytes** to store the length of the data.
- `LONGTEXT` have a maximum length of **4294967295 bytes (4GB)**
  and uses **4 more extra bytes** to store the length of the data.

If you know that you will always have less than 64kB of data in your HEX string, I would choose `TEXT`, otherwise go with `LONGTEXT`.

Comment: `BYTE` --> `BINARY`.

Comment: @RickJames: yes, you are right! I fixed my answer, thank you.
There is a `CHAR_BYTE` type, and I confused it with the type that OP has indicated in the question. :)

Comment: (I was confused, too.)  `CHAR(123) BYTE` (no underscore) is the same as `BINARY(123)`, and exists for combatibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you pack it into bytes (from hex), then `VARBINARY(...)` or `BLOB`.

If you keep it as hex, `VARCHAR(...) CHARACTER SET ascii` or `TEXT CHARACTER SET ascii`.  I mention ascii especially if your default is utf8; there is no need for utf8 for hex digits.